Ubuntu 24.04 deep sleep, power button to wake up reboot
I do an upgrade to ubuntu 24.04 (Neon) recently, and the deep sleep failed to works since.
In the previous version (ubuntu 22.04 neon, and all others ubuntu version), everything is fine: Entering a deep sleep make the power led blinking, pushing the power button is the only one that have any impact, and the laptop is starting again.
In Ubuntu 24.04 with the same laptop, I have hit several issues.
First one, the select sleep mode by default was s2idle:
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]

When I hit the power button, the laptop screen is shutting down, but the fan is working, and led power button is not blinking (so it seems that i was a software sleep)
So I change the grub config to force deep sleep, adding mem_sleep_default=deep to grub config :
$ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet nosplash mem_sleep_default=deep'

$ sudo update-grub

$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]

When I hit the power button, the laptop screen is shutting down, the fan is stopped and the power button is blinking, perfect !
But when I hit to power button to wake up, I see the power stopping to blink, but few seconds after, the laptop reboot to bios.
After restart, I see this log in journactl
Oct 15 22:29:46 udol systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
Oct 15 22:29:46 udol wpa_supplicant[936]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 15 22:29:46 udol systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Oct 15 22:29:46 udol systemd-sleep[5853]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Oct 15 22:29:46 udol kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)

And nothing more, like the power button was shutting down the laptop instead of wakeup.
I dig the whole internet to find a solution, but couldn't find any similar behavior :(

System info:
Operating System: KDE neon 6.2
KDE Plasma Version: 6.2.0
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-47-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1360P
Memory: 31,1 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: LG Electronics
Product Name: 16Z90R-G.AD78F
System Version: 0.1


I'm not sure if it'd even change antyhing, but I think on systemd you're supposed to change this kind of stuff by editing /etc/systemd/logind.conf?

Under 'settings'->'power'-> 'general'-> 'Power Button Behaviour' is it set to 'power off'?

No, it set up to "Sleep" on all mode (AC or battery)

I have a full commented version, with default value so. I've tried systemctl suspend, that make a s2idle : 2024-10-28T09:39:42.435052+01:00 udol kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)

This is just a stab in the dark, but could there be a UFI/BIOS setting at play here?

I have seen on advanced options a BIOS settings that is enabled, and since it was working well on ubuntu 22.04, I think it's not a hard issues but a software one
